# While using Knit to HTML, why is it showing error?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I am new in RStudio. I have completed a case-study and all the individual code chunks are working properly, but while knitting to HTML, I am getting an error message like. I dont know what to do. Please help!

[image]

Comment: It's difficult to help you without a REPREX. However, this is a typical error when the excel file is open while you try to read it from R.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.